# Using SED with wildcard

Tags: bash, sed, wildcard

I want to replace a string with wildcard but it doesn't work.

The string looks like "some-string-8"

I wrote

```
sed -i 's/string-*/string-0/g' file.txt
```

but the output is

```
some-string-08
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The asterisk (*) means "zero or more of the previous item".

If you want to match any single character use

```
sed -i 's/string-./string-0/g' file.txt
```

If you want to match any string (i.e. any single character zero or more times) use

```
sed -i 's/string-.*/string-0/g' file.txt
```

Comment: well, maybe my question was incomplete.... your command works for this fien. However if I have `some-string-8 -x --command acommand`, the output of executing that command is `some-string-0`. it will delete all characters after that. I want  `some-string-0 -x --command acommand`

Comment: what if you wish to use the wildcard in the replacement string?
example: replace 'AAA.*BBB' with 'CCC.*DDD'

Comment: turns out it's called back references, wildcards of the form (.*) will get replaced by \1, \2, ... etc. E.g. `sed -r 's/a (.*)cat/the \1bat/g' <<< "a womancat"` yields `the womanbat`. Figured this out from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188495/backreferences-in-sed-returning-wrong-value)

Answer (score 14):

So, the concept of a "wildcard" in Regular Expressions works a bit differently. In order to match "any character" you would use "."  The "*" modifier means, match any number of times.