# Backreferences in sed returning wrong value

Tags: regex, macos, sed

I am trying to replace an expression using sed. The regex works in vim but not in sed. I'm replacing the last dash before the number with a slash so

```
/www/file-name-1
```

should return

```
/www/file-name/1
```

I am using the following command but it keeps outputting /www/file-name/0 instead

```
sed 's/-[0-9]/\/\0/g' input.txt
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You must surround between parentheses the data to reference it later, and `sed` begins to count in 1. To recover all the characters matched without the need of parentheses, it is used the `&` symbol.

```
sed 's/-\([0-9]\)/\/\1/g' input.txt
```

That yields:

```
/www/file-name/1
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. I didn't notice @user2052491 was not using the parentheses.

Comment: the backslashes before the braces are not necessary, are they?

Answer (score 5):

You need to capture using parenthesis before you can back reference *(which start a `\1`)*. Try `sed -r 's|(.*)-|\1/|'`:

```
$ sed -r 's|(.*)-|\1/|' <<< "/www/file-name-1" 
/www/file-name/1
```

You can use any delimiter with `sed` so `/` isn't the best choice when the substitution contains `/`. The `-r` option is for extended regexp so the parenthesis don't need to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

It seems sed under OS X starts counting backreferences at 1. Try `\1` instead of `\0`

Comment: if I use \1 it returns "\1 not defined in the RE"

Comment: OS X / macOS has ancient UNIX tools. You can't use `-r` which means you need to escape the parentheses.

Comment: OS X's sed uses -E instead of -r to enable extended regex