# Shell Script : How to use Tee command with sed command

Tags: bash, unix, sed, tee

Before:

```
main 2>&1 | tee -a $log_file;
```

This is working fine but it is throwing stderr in $log_file as shown below. I want to replace:

```
"ERROR (version 5.3.0.0-213, build 1 from 2015-02-02_12-17-08 by buildguy) : (stderr)"
```

With:

```
"NOTE (version 5.3.0.0-213, build 1 from 2015-02-02_12-17-08 by buildguy) : (stderr)"
```

I want the version and date to be in regex format.

After:

```
main 2>&1 | tee -a | sed -i 's|ERROR (version 5.3.0.0-213, build 1 from 2015-02-02_12-17-08 by buildguy) : (stderr)|NOTE (version 5.3.0.0-213, build 1 from 2015-02-02_12-17-08 by buildguy) : (stderr)|g' $log_file;
```

[Error which are coming at downloading time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rtluz.png)

[Few lines coming at the end(The lines are jumbled)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h04wc.png)

Comment: So you want to disguise an error as a note. Big deal. _Why_?

Comment: `tee -a` won't do much on its own. It should be something like `main | sed | tee`.

Comment: main 2>&1 | sed -i 's|ERROR (version 5.3.0.0-213, build 1 from 2015-02-02_12-17-08 by buildguy) : (stderr)|NOTE (version 5.3.0.0-213, build 1 from 2015-02-02_12-17-08 by buildguy) : (stderr)|g' | tee -a $log_file .

Is this correct?

Comment: @SRK How should we know?! Does it work?

Comment: The command is not working for me. It is not replacing the ERROR line with NOTE line

Comment: Show some example output.

Comment: It is throwing an error like this.

** sed: no input files **

Comment: @SRK: Drop the `-i` from the sed options. That only works when using files, as it is for inplace editing

Comment: After removing -i it is working but I need regex in place version number(5.3.0.0-213) and date formats(2015-02-02_12-17-08). They might change in future even then the code should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try this;

```
main 2>&1 | sed "/ERROR.*[0-9]\{1\}.[0-9]\{1\}.[0-9]\{1\}.[0-9]\{1\}-[0-9]\{3\}.*20[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}_[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}.*(stderr)/ s/ERROR/INFO/" | tee -a $log_file
```

To find version, the regex;

```
[0-9]\{1\}.[0-9]\{1\}.[0-9]\{1\}.[0-9]\{1\}-[0-9]\{3\}  :
```

To find date, regex :  for example (2015-02-02_12-17-08)

```
20[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}_[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}
```

if date is like 2015-12-03 11.37.25, you should use

```
20[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\} [0-9]\{2\}.[0-9]\{2\}.[0-9]\{2\}
```

Comment: "main 2>&1 |sed 's|ERROR (version 5.3.0.0-213, build 1 from 2015-02-02_12-17-08 by buildguy) : (stderr)|NOTE (version 5.3.0.0-213, build 1 from 2015-02-02_12-17-08 by buildguy) : (stderr)|g' | tee -a $log_file"  was my previous command, so what are the changes to be done.

Comment: could you try this ; "main 2>&1 | sed "/ERROR.*5.3.0.0-213.*$(date +'%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S').*/ s/ERROR/INFO/" | tee -a $log_file"

Comment: if 2015-02-02_12-17-08 is not change;  "main 2>&1 | sed "/ERROR.*5.3.0.0-213.*2015-02-02_12-17-08.*/ s/ERROR/INFO/" | tee -a $log_file"

Comment: Timestamp and version will change if a new version of Pentaho comes.

Comment: Example : ERROR (version 6.0.1.0-386, build 1 from 2015-12-03 11.37.25 by buildguy) :

Comment: 1)ERROR (version 5.3.0.0-213, build 1 from 2015-02-02_12-17-08 by buildguy) :

2)ERROR(version 5.3.0.0-213, build 1 from 2015-02-02_12-17-08 by buildguy) : (stderr) .

Only the 2nd one should be replaced. But by using the current regex, both of them are replaced. The regex should contain : (stderr).

Comment: main 2>&1 | sed "/ERROR.*[0-9]\{1\}.[0-9]\{1\}.[0-9]\{1\}.[0-9]\{1\}-[0-9]\{3\}.*20[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}_[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}.*: (stderr).*/ s/ERROR/INFO/" | tee -a $log_file

Comment: Yeah.It is working perfectly.
I need small concern. Is there any regex for this.
After (stderr) also there are some digits and characters.
Can we have a regex for them also?

Comment: @SRK : could you give a sample digits and characters after (stderr).

Comment: INFO (version 5.3.0.0-213, build 1 from 2015-02-02_12-17-08 by buildguy) : (stderr)   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
INFO (version 5.3.0.0-213, build 1 from 2015-02-02_12-17-08 by buildguy) : (stderr)                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
INFO (version 5.3.0.0-213, build 1 from 2015-02-02_12-17-08 by buildguy) : (stderr) 
INFO (version 5.3.0.0-213, build 1 from 2015-02-02_12-17-08 by buildguy) : (stderr)   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0

Comment: INFO (version 5.3.0.0-213, build 1 from 2015-02-02_12-17-08 by buildguy) : (stderr)   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
INFO (version 5.3.0.0-213, build 1 from 2015-02-02_12-17-08 by buildguy) : (stderr)   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
INFO (version 5.3.0.0-213, build 1 from 2015-02-02_12-17-08 by buildguy) : (stderr)   8  176M    8 14.4M    0     0  6766k      0  0:00:26  0:00:02  0:00:24 6764k

Comment: @SRK : after stderr, there are many difference values, So I tried to find a correct regex, but I can't

Comment: I have attached the exact screen shot of it.
Can you please look into it?

Comment: While running the script getting an error like this.
SCRIPT::main 2>&1 | sed "/ERROR.*[0-9]\{1\}.[0-9]\{1\}.[0-9]\{1\}.[0-9]\{1\}-[0-9]\{3\}.*20[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}_[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}.*(stderr)/ s/ERROR/NOTE/" | tee -a $log_file
ERROR::2016/10/17 05:19:17 - file_reports_urls - NOTE (version 5.3.0.0-213, build 1 from 2015-02-02_12-17-08 by buildguy) : (stderr) curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL

Comment: SCRIPT::main 2>&1 | sed "/ERROR.*[0-9]\{1\}.[0-9]\{1\}.[0-9]\{1\}.[0-9]\{1\}-[0-9]\{‌​3\}.*20[0-9]\{2\}-[0‌​-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}_‌​[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\‌​}-[0-9]\{2\}.*(stder‌​r)/ s/ERROR/NOTE/" | tee -a $log_file

Comment: ERROR::2016/10/17 05:19:17 - file_reports_urls - NOTE (version 5.3.0.0-213, build 1 from 2015-02-02_12-17-08 by buildguy) : (stderr) curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL

Comment: @SRK; I think, this is not sed problem, probably, curl command  in main throw this, due to illegal characters found in URL.

Comment: Exactly,thanks for your information.
But here few lines are skipping because of the sed command.
Example:
1) INFO  2016-10-14 02:51:57 - YT_BULK_API ETL MASTER LOAD

Comment: INFO  2016-10-14 02:51:57 - Set working directory: /home/pentahodev/repository/yt_bulk_api

Comment: INFO  2016-10-14 02:51:57 - Cleaning log files older than 10 days

Comment: INFO  2016-10-14 02:51:57 - YT_BULK_API ETL Master Load will run from Run Seq - 1

Comment: The sed command is skipping all the outcome of main 2>&1 except which are starting from ERROR.
Can you please change the regex?

Comment: @SRK: date and time connected space or _ char so, you can use this; main 2>&1 | sed "/ERROR.*[0-9]\{1\}.[0-9]\{1\}.[0-9]\{1\}.[0-9]\{1\}-[0-9]\{3\}.*20[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}[_, ][0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}.*(stderr)/ s/ERROR/INFO/" | tee -a $log_file

Comment: Can I ask you a question if you don't mind?
main 2>&1 is also returning other lines which are starting with "INFO" and "Running" lines along with ERROR lines.

Can we change Regex to allow INFO and Running lines?

Comment: maybe this help. But I cant  test this; main 2>&1 | sed "/ERROR.*[0-9]\{1\}.[0-9]\{1\}.[0-9]\{1\}.[0-9]\{1\}-[0-9]\{‌​3\}.*20[0-9]\{2\}-[0‌​-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}[‌​_, ][0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}.*(stderr)/ s/ERROR/INFO/;/\(RUNNING\|INFO\)/p" | tee -a $log_file

Comment: By using the previous command also INFO and Running lines are coming but they are present at somewhere in the middle.
Few of @ERROR lines coming at exact place and few are at the end.

Comment: I have attached the screen shot. After job got executed successfully it is showing downloading status.

Comment: main 2>&1 | sed "/\(Running\|INFO\|ERROR.*version.*build.*(stderr)\)/ s/ERROR/#INFO/g" | tee -a $log_file
Will the above command work?

Answer (score 1):

You should precise your need, it's pretty hard to read your code by now.

There is two option here :

- You get the mainstream and alternate him before saving into your log file
- You format your log file at the end

**First option**

I can't test it, however, it should be like this :

```
main 2>&1 | SED COMMAND | tee -a $log_file
```

**Second option**

Tested, it works.

```
sed -i "s/ERROR (version 5.3.0.0-213, build 1 from 2015-02-02_12-17-08 by buildguy) : (stderr)/NOTE (version 5.3.0.0-213, build 1 from 2015-02-02_12-17-08 by buildguy) : (stderr)/g" $log_file
```

Sed will edit the file specified inline because of -i option.

**REGEX**

If you want to change all *ERROR* by *NOTE*, then, you should just use this sed command

```
sed -i "s/ERROR/NOTE/g" $log_file;
```

And if you want to be more specific, take a look at this answer : [using SED with wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189120/using-sed-with-wildcard)

Comment: I don't want ERROR to be replaced everywhere. It should be replaced if it is stderr only and regex should only for (5.3.0.0-213) and (2015-02-02_12-17-08) because they may change in future.

Comment: Then the answer of Mustafa should do the tricks, you can find more information about it in the link I gave you.  :)

Comment: Thanks. And for the reader, don't forget `sed -u` (--unbuffered load minimal amounts of data from the input files and flush the output buffers more often), if you think that sed doesn't work: the pipe stream is in the buffer.