# Replace PATH element with SED of multiple xml file in bash

Tags: xml, bash, unix, sed, automation

I have managed to replace 1 xml file. However, I have 10 of them from test1.xml to test30.xml and they have different Paths at the end:

```
test1.xml
...
<examples>
<example path='/test/test123/st1.txt'/>
<examples>
...
```

```
test2.xml
...
<examples>
<example path='/test/test123/te2.txt'/>
<examples>
...
```

to

```
test30.xml
...
<examples>
<example path='/test/test123/removethispart.txt'/>
<examples>
...
```

to this:

```
...
<examples>
<example path='/test/test123/'/>
<examples>
...
```

Previously, I used this and it can change one file
`sed -i "s#<example path='/test/test123/st1.txt'/>#<example path=/test/test123/>#" test1.xml`

However, I would like to change multiple files at once and the below script executed but upon `cat` the xml file, it did not show the changes

`sed -i "s#<example path='/test/test123/*.txt'/>#<example path='/test/test123/'>#" *.xml`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using SED with wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189120/using-sed-with-wildcard)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. Try

```
sed -i "s#<example path='/test/test123/.*\.txt'/>#<example path='/test/test123/'>#" *.xml
```

With regular expressions, the pattern to match anything is `.*` and a literal period needs to be quoted with a backslash, `\.`.